# ¿Qué significa "mejor que aquí sí que están" en la siguiente conversación?

Tags: significado, modismos, sintaxis

Vi el siguiente ejemplo en un libro de ejercicios:

> - Manuel dice que en aquel país todo el mundo es rico, pero no creo que allí se aten los perros con longaniza.
> - Hombre, mejor que aquí sí que están.

No entiendo qué significa la oración "mejor que aquí sí que están", específicamente cómo funciona "sí que están". ¿Está expresando que aunque este país probablemente no sea tan rico, al menos sería mejor que donde viven ellos dos? ¿O está diciendo algo completamente diferente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Manuel dice que en aquel país todo el mundo es rico, pero no creo que allí se aten los perros con longaniza.

En la expresión **No creo que allí se aten los perros con longaniza** se indica que en aquel país no son prósperos.

> Hombre, mejor que aquí sí que están

A pesar de eso **mejor que aquí sí que están** .

*Sí* cuando lleva tilde sirve para hacer una afirmación, en este caso de lo descrito anteriormente **Mejor que aquí**.

Reescribiendo para entender mejor:

> A pesar de no ser prósperos, están mejor que aquí.

Está expresando que en el país del que habla Manuel están mejor.

Comment: La razón por la que pone "mejor que aquí sí que están" en vez de simplemente "Están mejor que aquí", es que el primer interlocutor dice "no creo que allí se aten los perros con longaniza" que significa "no creo que sean tan prósperos".

La otra persona responde algo como "puede que allá tampoco sean tan prósperos, pero siguen estando mejor que aquí".

Comment: Si, es verdad, estaba atacando la idea principal sin tener en cuenta ese contraste, ahora edito. Gracias!